# How to use C# object from F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I have the following C# code.

```
namespace MyMath {
    public class Arith {
        public Arith() {}
        public int Add(int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

And I came up with the F# code named testcs.fs to use this object.

```
open MyMath.Arith
let x = Add(10,20)
```

When I run the following command

```
fsc -r:MyMath.dll testcs.fs
```

I got this error message.

```
/Users/smcho/Desktop/cs/namespace/testcs.fs(1,13): error FS0039: The namespace 'Arith' is 
not defined

/Users/smcho/Desktop/cs/namespace/testcs.fs(3,9): error FS0039: The value or constructor 
'Add' is not defined
```

What might be wrong? I used mono for .NET environment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try

```
open MyMath
let arith = Arith() // create instance of Arith
let x = arith.Add(10, 20) // call method Add
```

*Arith* in your code is class name, you cannot open it like namespace.  Possibly you are confused with ability to open F# modules so its functions can be used without qualification

Answer (score 7):

Since `Arith` is a class and not a namespace, you can't open it.  You can do this instead:

```
open MyMath
let x = Arith().Add(10,20)
```

Answer (score 3):

With open, you can only open namespaces are modules (similarly to the C# using keyword).
Namespaces are defined with the namespace keyword, and act the same in both C# and F#. However, modules are in fact just static classes, having only static members - F# just hides that from you.

If you look at an F# code with the reflector, you'll see that your module has been compiled as a static class.
For this reason you can only use static classes as modules in F#, and in your example, the class is not static, so in order to use it, you have to create an object instance - just like you'd do in C#.