# Is it possible to define public static readonly field in F#?

Tags: f#

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747494/how-to-define-a-public-static-readonly-field) is similar, but I do not see the answer which would satisfy me.

So, how does the equivalent of `public static readonly string Name = ...;` look in F#?

I can define `static member Name = ...`, but this creates static readonly property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to get a public static readonly field in F#.

If you use `static let`, you end up with a private field (and, in fact, I think this is actually compiled as a private field with a private static property `Xyz`):

```
type B() = 
  static let Xyz = 1
```

You can define actual fields with `val`, but this does not support initialization (so you need to set it in a static constructor) and the compiler requires such fields to be private:

```
type A() = 
  static do A.Xyz <- 1
  [<DefaultValue>] 
  static val mutable private Xyz : int
```

If you try to make the field `public`, you will get:

> error FS0881: Static 'val' fields in types must be mutable, private and marked with the '[]' attribute. They are initialized to the 'null' or 'zero' value for their type. Consider also using a 'static let mutable' binding in a class type.

I think the error message gives an answer to your question. That said, I cannot think of a good reason why you would need a static public field - a `let` binding in a module should typically cover the use cases that you might have for a static public field (unless you need this because some library looks for static public fields via reflection...).

Comment: Just curious, I am ok with `static member val`. I also see that F# adds additional check that static constructor successfully ran and value was initialized.

Comment: @PavelVoronin Yep, I think the checks for succesfull initialization are exactly the reason why F# prevents normal public static fields...

Comment: Btw, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.missing.value?view=netcore-3.1) is an example =)

Answer (score 0):

The followin is not a field but is static and readonly:

```
type T() =
  static let _name = GetNameFromSomeWhere()
  static member Name with get() = _name
```